# Field calculator for output line from ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

Calculate values for only a single feature in Model Builder output.

How do I calculate a field for only the newly generated feature? In my  model everything goes fine but the calculate field operates on all the features in output layer not just the newly created feature.

I am attempting to achieve this using a selection in my model.

[image]

Comment: How about isolating the features to be appended in a temporary feature class, calculating the value and *then* append to the new table.

Comment: Seems nice. Let me try

Comment: But it append previously selected line too with lastest calculate value..

Comment: You need to clear the selection and make a new one